# Angular 2 to 4 - error in Rxjs Subject.d.ts

Tags: angular, upgrade

**When we started multiple projects, 3 in ng2 and 1 in ng4, independently its all working. One project uses datatables.net too. When trying to integrate and upgrade all to ng4, i got this error.**

1. Login is a component in 1 app, and others uses a login.html - what is the better approach?
2. error in compiling

   > > Class 'Subject' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable'.
   > >       Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
   > >         Type '(operator: Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type '(operator: Operator) => Observable'.
   > >           Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
   > >             Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

rxjs was version 5.4.2

> solved versions
>   [rxjs was upgraded to 5.4.2 - and downgraded to 5.0.1]
>   To mention the detailed issue after the app working is

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.2",
    "alertify.js": "^1.0.12",
    "angular-datatables": "^4.1.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "2.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "2.2.0",
    "datatables.net-buttons-dt": "1.3.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder": "1.3.3",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-dt": "1.3.3",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.15",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs": "^2.1.1",
    "datatables.net-scroller": "1.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nanoscroller": "0.8.7",
    "primeng": "4.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.5",
    "@types/datatables.net-buttons": "~1.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.17",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.7.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack": "3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you research this at all? It was pretty easy to find related issues: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2705

Comment: mmm it looks like if you don't update ALL your packages correctly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error happened with the upgrade of TypeScript.

You should upgrade all your packages. But it's possible that some packages have not taken the last TypeScript modification.

Then you can contribute to those projects to make them compatible, or you should downgrade to the last Angular 4 version that supports TypeScript 4.1.

Comment: Thanx jon, since new in the ng and all of a sudden the migration happens, somewhere it went wrong with the said upgrade.